# Extracting multiple values from string and ordering them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have values within a Notes field consisting of values such as this where abc represents different words:

**Request Notes: VAR - abc abc abc abc abc**

Unfortunately the design of how the data is stored is very poor, and I need to pull out the Note Type for each "Required Notes:" record. It also needs ordering from most recent to oldest (last part of the string to first part of the string).

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData
(
    ClientID int,
    Notes varchar(8000)
)
insert into #TestData
(
    ClientID,
    Notes
)
select
    1,
    'Request Notes: VAR - abc abc abc abc abc'
union all
select
    2,
    'Request Notes: OZR - abc abc abc abc abc Request Notes: ACC - abc abc abc abc abc Request Notes: TYU - abc abc abc abc abc'
union all
select
    3,
    'Request Notes: TYU - abc abc abc abc abc Request Notes: VAR - abc abc abc abc abc'
```

This is how I expect the output to be for the above examples:

```
--Expected Output

Client ID       Type    Order
1               VAR     1
2               TYU     1
2               ACC     2
2               OZR     3
3               VAR     1
3               TYU     2
```

I have this together so far which extracts OZR, but I'm stumped on how to get the others and order the list into the expected output above.

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(500) = 'Request Notes: OZR - abc abc abc abc abc Request Notes: ACC - abc abc abc abc abc Request Notes: TYU - abc abc abc abc abc'

SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX(':', @Text), CHARINDEX('-',@text) - CHARINDEX(':', @Text) + Len('-')),':',''),'-',''))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *openjson* to extract your data as an array and filter:

```
select d.ClientId, n.*
from #testdata d
cross apply (
  select 
    Left(j.[value],3) [Type],
    Row_Number() over(order by Convert(int,j.[key]) desc) [Order] 
  from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(notes,'Notes: ', '","'),'"]')) j
  where j.[value] != 'Request'
 )n;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eYbi3HTI)

Comment: Cheers Stu, nice solution - only issue is the ordering of the data doesn't match - is it possible to change that around ?

Comment: @Philip I missed that - amended answer above to sort in reverse order.

Comment: Cheers Stu, appreciate the help. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive CTE version. It splits the string based on finding "Request Notes:" then does a left/right combo to extract the 3 letter code. It iterates the order as it builds. Then you select from the CTE and only take rows where there's some NotesRemainder:

```
    ;
WITH CTESplit
AS (
    SELECT ClientID,
           RIGHT(LEFT(Notes, CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', Notes) + 17), 3) AS NotesPart,
           RIGHT(Notes, LEN(Notes) - CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', Notes) - 17) AS NotesRemainder,
           -1 AS [Order]
    FROM #TestData
    WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', Notes) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTESplit.ClientID,
           RIGHT(LEFT(CTESplit.NotesRemainder, CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', CTESplit.NotesRemainder) + 17), 3),
           RIGHT(CTESplit.NotesRemainder, LEN(CTESplit.NotesRemainder) - CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', CTESplit.NotesRemainder)),
           CTESplit.[Order] - 1
    FROM CTESplit
    WHERE CTESplit.NotesRemainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', CTESplit.NotesRemainder) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTESplit.ClientID,
           RIGHT(LEFT(CTESplit.NotesRemainder, CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', CTESplit.NotesRemainder) + 17), 3),
           NULL,
           CTESplit.[Order] - 1
    FROM CTESplit
    WHERE CTESplit.NotesRemainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('Request Notes:', CTESplit.NotesRemainder) = 0
)
SELECT CS.ClientID,
       CS.NotesPart AS Type,
       CS.[Order] +(SELECT MIN([Order])*-1 FROM CTESplit WHERE ClientID = CS.ClientID) AS [Order]
FROM CTESplit AS CS
WHERE CS.NotesRemainder IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CS.ClientID,
         CS.[Order] ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks Ricky, similar to Stu's answer below, the ordering is not right though where 1 should be the last value in the list.

Comment: I've tweaked the code; changes in both the CTE definition and then in the SELECT

Comment: Thanks Ricky, appreciate the help. Merry Christmas! I thought Stu's answer was cleaner but thanks as well.